# High cpu usage from grpc AsyncServerStreamingCall

Tags: c#, blazor, grpc, blazor-server-side, grpc-web

i'm trying to stream some log feed over grpc and it's working great.
But the streaming causes very high cpu usage, even though it's not necessary.
Logs are coming in with 100-500ms inbetween.

```
var logStream = client.StreamSessionLogs(new SessionRequest() {Id = sessionId}, new CallOptions());

while (await logStream.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
{
    await UpdateLogs(logStream.ResponseStream.Current.LatestLogs);
    Console.WriteLine("streamed");
}
```

I've tried modifying my loop to only MoveNext every 500 ms, but the moment i add delay, no updates are retrieved at all after the delay.
I don't see why this would be, but maybe i'm missing something?

```
while (await logStream.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
{
    await UpdateLogs(logStream.ResponseStream.Current.LatestLogs);
    Console.WriteLine("streamed");
    await Task.Delay(10);
}
```

Even with 1 ms delay, streaming completely stops.

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Does the high CPU usage only occur while a debugger is attached? Or does it also happen with a release version?

Comment: What you're describing seems pretty weird, but I suspect there's some problem with your application logic (impossible to tell what exactly as you only included a snippets of your entire solution). Did you verify that that the server actually sends out any logs? Btw just awaiting responseStream.MoveNext() isn't something that would cause high CPU load by itself - it only happens if way too many messages are sent by the server. Perhaps you should reconfigure your server to send multiple log messages in a batch in each response?